# Probability of at least one boolean random variable being true in a network of positively-correlated boolean variables

Tags: probability, correlation, random-variable

#### My question

I have a set of $N$ random boolean variables $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ (each can be $1$ or $0$). For every $i \in [1, N]$, I know that

$$P(X_i = 1) = p^*$$

Now, I know that the variables are positively correlated, i.e., for every $i, j \in [1, N]$ I have:

$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 1) \geq p^*$$
$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 0) \leq p^*$$

(but I can't find an expression for those conditional probabilities)

Is the probability of at least **one** variable being $1$ larger or smaller than if they were independent?

#### The extreme case

Consider the case where all the variables are completely correlated, so that for every $i, j \in [1, N]$

$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 1) = 1$$
$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 0) = 0$$

Then the probability $p$ of at least one random variable being $1$ is $p = p^*$ (either all of them are $1$ or none is).

While in the case where they are completely independent, i.e.,

$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 1) = p^*$$
$$P(X_i = 1 | X_j = 0) = p^*$$

I have

$$p = 1 - (1 - p^*)^N$$

and since $(1 - p^*) < 1 \implies (1 - p^*)^N < (1 - p^*)$ I have

$$p > p^*$$

So in the limiting case I know that being positively correlated makes the probability of at least **one** variable being $1$ smaller. Is this true for any positive correlation?

Comment: In the dependence scheme, does it hold that $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1| X_j = 1, X_k =1) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1| X_j = 1)  = \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1| X_k =1) $? I think you need some more independence assumptions, since it could in principle hold simultaneously that $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1| X_j = 1) \geq p^{\ast}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1| X_j = 1, X_k=1) < p^{\ast}$.

Comment: This question is answered at [your other posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113686/probability-of-at-least-one-boolean-random-variable-being-true-in-a-network-of-p)